# Refine Slide plugin to work on jQuery 1.9 and up

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, compatibility

I downloaded this fantastic responsive 3d plugin, however was not mentained for 3 years already and does not work with jQuery 1.9 and up. I tried to find out how to fix it to make it work with jQuery v1.11.1 or at least v1.9 but its beyond me.

Based on this document

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

I think problem might be because they use `add()` on this line

```
$images = $this.find('img').add( $this.filter('img') ),
```

However I am not sure, JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4a6685qg/

Note when you on jQuery v1.8.3. arrows make transition between images, when you switch to v1.9 it stops working.

Comment: You nailed it. Read the jquery migrate plugin section in that guide that you posted and then follow the link for the migration patch

Comment: Just tried with jQquery Migrate v1.2.1 on both site and jsFiddle without luck, migrate supposed to re-add whatever was removed in 1.9, but it still not sliding http://jsfiddle.net/4a6685qg/1/